# Get current date and time to commit message to git

Tags: command-line, scripts, backup, git

I am writing a shell script to auto push the backups in to git using crontab. How can I get the current date and time into the commit message. This is my script:

```bsh
cd /var/www/html/myweb
php bin/magento setup:backup --code --media --db
cp /var/www/html/myweb/var/backups/* /home/myweb/backups/myweb/backups/
cd /home/myweb/backups/myweb
git add .
git commit -m  "date +"%D %T""
git push
```

Comment: for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD`;do echo -e `git show --format="%ci %cr" $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r
Raw

Comment: @HarshPatel Can you include an answer with instructions on how and why to do that? [Leaving a half-answer as a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments) can often cause more harm than good. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Command Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) to get the current date and time when your script is run:

```bsh
git commit -m "$(date +"%D %T")"
```

Alternatively you could save `date`'s output in a variable, e.g. if you want to capture the time the script was *started* at, add as the first command e.g.

```bsh
timestamp=$(date +"%D %T")
```

and use it later like:

```bsh
git commit -m "$timestamp: Backup"
```

If this is really your whole script, remember to add a [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) as the first line. I always try to avoid `cd` in scripts and rather give full paths, last but not least it helps to keep the code clean and easily understandable if you store long paths in variables:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
path1=/var/www/html/myweb
path2=/home/myweb/backups/myweb

php "$path1/bin/magento" setup:backup --code --media --db
cp "$path1/var/backups/*" "$path2/backups/"
git add "$path2"
git commit -m "$(date +"%D %T")"
git push
```

Note that you can't use `~` in a path when you do it like that because variables are expanded *after* the tilde, you can use `$HOME` though.